# Meteor.status() is not a reactive data source?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, reactive-programming, angular-meteor

We're trying to do the following to show a connection status on our app:

```
this.helpers({
    userBlock: () => {
        //...
        return {
            name: name,
            connectionStatus: Meteor.status().connected
        }
    }
});
```

However the helper doesn't re run after the server is disconnected. Outputting `Meteor.status().connected` variable directly into the template, both via $scope and controller reference doesn't see its value updating either. Any ideas on how we can get the helper to re run with `Meteor.status().connected` change?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I implemented and it works as expected. When server is down, the template renders "Disconnected" message and it disappears when server is back again.

```
var SHOW_CONNECTION_ISSUE_KEY = 'showConnectionIssue';
Session.setDefault(SHOW_CONNECTION_ISSUE_KEY, false);

Meteor.startup(function () {

   // Only show the connection error box if it has been 5 seconds since
   // the app started
   setTimeout(function () {
       // Show the connection error box
       Session.set(SHOW_CONNECTION_ISSUE_KEY, true);
   }, 5000);
});

Template.header.helpers({
   connected: function() {
       if (Session.get(SHOW_CONNECTION_ISSUE_KEY)) {
           return Meteor.status().connected; 
       } else {
           return true;
       }
}});
```

and in template:

```
{{#unless connected}}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            Disconnected
        </div>
{{/unless}}
```